# Path resolution issues with NPM modules vs apps

Tags: node.js, npm

I am writing a module that will be used as a dependency for Node.js apps. In some cases, it will be a dependency of a dependency, which means the path resolution will change, and currently I am having a problem with that. Namely, when my module is a dependency of a dependency, my module will still look to the app root, not the root of the dependency.

I think the shortest way to ask a question on how to solve this is to find out the best way to determine if the module is a dependency or not.

So the way to do that would be to get the `__dirname` of the file in the index of my module and then navigate up one directory to see if that directory is named `node_modules`.

Is there a better way to do this? Is there a better way to determine if the code being invoked is being invoked from a dependency of the app or from the app itself?

Visually speaking, it looks like this

```
--app
---/node_modules
-----/A
-----/B
```

my module is called A

A could be used by app, or it could be used by B

if it's used by app, I can use the app-root-path module to quickly determine the root. But if my module is used by B, how will I know that? It will matter for resolving paths.

Here is the entiriety of the code in my module:

```
var appRoot = require('app-root-path');
var path = require('path');

var configs = {};


function checkIfDependency(){

    var temp = path.resolve(path.normalize(__dirname + '/../'));
    return path.basename(temp) === 'node_modules';

}


module.exports = function (identifier, pathToProvider) {


    if (String(identifier).indexOf('*') < 0) {
        throw new Error('did not pass in an identifier to univ-config');
    }

    if (configs[identifier]) {
        return configs[identifier];
    }
    else {
        if (pathToProvider) {
            try {
                var configPath;
                if (path.isAbsolute(pathToProvider)) {  //consumer of this lib has been so kind as to provide an absolute path, the risk is now yours
                    configPath = path.normalize(pathToProvider);
                }
                else if(checkIfDependency()){  //univ-config is being invoked from a dependency
                    configPath = path.normalize(??? + '/' + pathToProvider);
                }
                else{  //univ-config is being invoked from an app
                    configPath = path.normalize(appRoot + '/' + pathToProvider);
                }

                var f = require(configPath);
                return configs[identifier] = f();
            }
            catch (err) {
                throw new Error('univ-config could not resolve the path to your config provider module - given as:' + pathToProvider);
            }
        }
        else {
            throw new Error('no config matched the identifier but no path to config provider was passed to univ-config');
        }
    }

};
```

Comment: app-root-path module will give me the app-root directory, but depending on whether my module will be used by an app versus by another dependency, will determine path resolution inside my module

Comment: I added a visual, let me know if that helps at all to clarify the question or not thanks

Comment: Can you show an example (source code) usage where you experience `"my module will still look to the app root, not the root of the dependency."` How are you using the path you are resolving?

Comment: sure thanks, I added the code..my module is a configuration module so it gets more meta than usual, but the user of the module will invoke mine by calling require('univ-config')(x,y); where x,y are identifier/pathToProvider

Comment: I understand the question now. You might be able to make something work using `module.parent.filename`, but that will introduce its own set of issues if your module is required from more than one other module. Maybe you can use the `caller-id` module with something like `require('caller-id').getData().filePath`.

Comment: yeah thanks, you are right, that might be the only way to do this, without the user of my lib explicitly passing __dirname...but if I had users pass __dirname or module, that might be enough

Comment: Yeah, that or require that they I've you an absolute path for `pathToProvider`, and simply throw an exception if the path they give you is not absolute.